# Jenkins json REST api with CORS request using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, rest, jenkins, cors

I'm trying to use the Jenkins json API and cannot get the authentication to work.

setup:

- Jenkins security: `Jenkin’s own user database`
- access: `Matrix-gebaseerde beveiliging`
- CORS via [Jenkins CORS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin)
- using username/api token of a registered user

tried:

```
var username = "username";
var apiToken = "apiToken";

// username / api-token on url (basic authentication)
$.ajax({
  url: "http://"+username+":"+apiToken+"@host:port/job/test/api/json",
  method: "GET"
});

// username / api-token supplied using jQuery's username/password properties
$.ajax({
  url: "http://host:port/job/test/api/json",
  method: "GET",
  username: username,
  password: apiToken
});

// username / api-token by setting "Authorization" header directly
$.ajax({
  url: "http://host:port/job/test/api/json",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + apiToken)
  }
});
```

All these attempts result in the same result:
**response: 403 Forbidden**

Comment: No. Sorry. Do you have any leads

Comment: Just posted a possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had some success with this. Note: I had to add two add_header lines to our nginx proxy config...

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://localhost:9001';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
```

Then I can do this in Jenkins. It seems to not need any user/pass/token as long as my browser is authorised in another tab (shares the same session/cookie).

```
$.ajax({
  url:'https://myserver.com/job/MYJOB/lastBuild/api/json',
  method: 'GET',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function() {
  console.error(arguments);
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know (next week?).

Comment: It worked! Thanks! As you already said, You have to be authenticated in the same browser. In order to fully authenticate too, you could use:   

    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:apiToken')}

Answer (score 3):

In response to @nick providing the answer:

I've used Jenkins [Cors Filter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin) to add the CORS headers which are needed:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origins: http://mydomain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

The solution of @nick requires you to be authenticated in the same browser.
To provide credentials via the REST call I've added an `"Authorization" header` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'https://myserver.com/job/MYJOB/lastBuild/api/json',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:apitoken')}
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function() {
  console.error(arguments);
});
```

The `apitoken` can be retrieved via the configuration of the specific user to use in Jenkins itself.

Comment: I installed that plugin but it didn't seem to do anything. Either related to jenkins needing to restart (we had loads of jobs we couldn't kill at the time) or the nginx proxy may have been filtering them out?! Either way, that's why I put the headers in the nginx proxy.