# Jenkins job API with authentication user Token not working

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm trying to create a Jenkins job via REST API with user authentication I've found curl

> curl JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters 
> --user USER:TOKEN 
> --data id=123 --data verbosity=high

Jenkins's job is creating w/o authentication.

With authentication receiving 403(Forbbiden) Error

```
`${jenkinsApi}/job/buildWithParameters?token=1234&job=${jobName}&git=${gitURL}&giturl=${dotGit}&typeOfProject=${typeofprojectvalue}&remoteAlias=${targetAlais}`,
```

Headers passing user and token

```
 jcreds="myuser:"+JenkinsAuthToken;
 const jHeaders = {
Authorization: 'Basic ' + jcreds,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
};
```

the above throws `403 forbidden error[CORS missing Allow Origin]`. Where I'm going wrong?

**Update Code :**

```
const dataP={
  token:1234,
  job:jobName,
  git:gitURL,
  giturl:dotGit,
  typeOfProject:typeofprojectvalue,
  remoteAlias:targetAlais,

};console.log("datappp",dataP)
await axios.post(
  `${jenkinsApi}/job/buildWithParameters`,dataP,
  {
    headers:jHeaders,
 
  }
)
```

I'm facing

**NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see if this helps you. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508417/jenkins-json-rest-api-with-cors-request-using-jquery`

Comment: @mdabdullah not working